# jQuery UI Theme too big

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

When I download a jQuery-ui theme, what do I have to add to get the defaults looking the same as in the jQuery-ui demo page?

The dialog I'm seeing out of the box is HUGE (see below).  I know all the css is available to me from the demo page, but I'm not really a CSS expert, and don't know what to take, and what to leave.

[image]

**EDIT**

Here's a [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/w92TY/) showing the same.

**EDIT**

Comment: I think you need theme roller for that... have you [looked here](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)?

Comment: Do you have any CSS of your own set?

Comment: @Joseph, I'm using the pre-canned Redmond theme *from* the theme roller.  I've tried what it's given me, and also the google-shared version of the same.  Both result in this bloated dialog  <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />

Comment: @8vius - I tried removing ALL other css anywhere else on my page—no change.

Comment: can we see a demo or http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @Joseph:  http://jsfiddle.net/w92TY/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I see what the issue is :P

```
body{font-size:10px;}
```

The sizes are relative to the page (more of a fluid layout). So (at least in the fiddle) changing the font-size of the body fixes it.  Just change your pages' font sizes and the dialog will change with it.

http://jsfiddle.net/hnBmC/

Comment: Thank you!  I don't normally ask follow-up questions, but I think this is related: how do I revert to the browser's default font-size elsewhere?  Right now I apply this class `.defaultText { font-size: 14px; }` to the div that has most of my content.  Is there something I can put instead of `font-size: 14px` that will revert the text to what it would otherwise be?

Comment: You can get the user's default font size with `medium` as the value.  [See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/font-size#section_3).  Thus you would use `font-size: medium;`

Answer (score 41):

The best way is : change base jQuery-ui font-size:

```
.ui-widget{font-size:12px;}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4D5RN/) for an example.

Comment: This should be the marked answer since it affects only the JQuery UI elements and not all in the body like the marked solution.

Comment: don't forget to add `!important` attribute. `.ui-widget{font-size:12px !important;}`

Comment: -1: Changing just `.ui-widget` is NOT enough.  Check the jquery-ui.css file for `font-size` settings - there are lots that use various multiple of `em`.  You'd have to change ALL of them to get something consistent.  Better to set a single `font-size` in an enclosing container, such as a `<div>`.

Answer (score 1):

For this dialog header issue you can simply add the below attribute to the dialog's parent class

```
.ui-dialog { clear: both; }
```

For reference,
[jQuery UI Dialog Titlebar too tall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036331/jquery-ui-dialog-titlebar-too-tall/16772775#16772775)

Comment: Changing document flow doesn't affect text size - you need to do something to change font-size.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at themeroller.css with your favourite web page inspector then you'll find this:-

```
#themeroller {
    font-size: 10px;
}
#themeroller button,
#themeroller input,
#themeroller select,
#themeroller textarea {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

A bit of digging in the HTML reveals that `<div id="themeroller">` encompasses the entire "demo" area of the page so ALL the jquery-ui widgets are inside it and therefore take their font-sizes relative to these values.

Looking at my "too big" page, normal text has a font-size of 18px.  This comes from .ui-widget in themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css having `font-size: 1em` which it calculates from my browser's base font size of 16px.  I discovered this base size by inspecting a simple document:

```
<html><body>
<span style="font-size: 100%">here is some plain body text</span
</body></html>
```

So the answer to the question of how to set the font size for jquery-ui widgets is to set the font-size for an enclosing element.  `<body>` (as recommended by [Joseph Marikle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/854246/joseph-marikle)) is guaranteed to hit everything but might be too wide for your needs, in which case you should use an inner `<div>` instead.  `<span>` is probably evil because you shouldn't wrap block-level things in non-blocks - but check that assertion with the CSS Style Police, I'm just a hacker!

I was going to rant about why the designers chose to base heights on `em`, which is a *width*, rather than `ex`, which is a *height*.  However, I suspect the answer is that `em` gives you more consistent results over a wider range of fonts, as most times the height of an 'l' is about the same as the width of an 'm'.  Conversely, if you used `2ex` as your basic measure then you'd get weird heights in fonts with very short or very long ascenders and descenders when compared to the height of an 'x'.

Answer (score 0):

jquery ui is a framework you can modify it by creation new or existing theme:

```
/*css which made title too large, reduce padding as you need*/
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar {
    padding: 0.5em 1em 0.3em;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: it's not the padding... it's the font-size of .ui-widget

Answer (score 0):

you can use this css rule to apply smaller font size:

`.ui-dialog{font-size: 62.5%;}`

Comment: There are more classes affecting font-size than `.ui-dialog` - look in the jquery-ui.css file for `font-size` to find them all.